# Set validation alert to custom text box

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate a simple text field with HTML and Javascript. I have everything working the way I want it but I would like to have the validation alerts appear differently. Currently, they are the standard pop-ups but I would like them to appear as text underneath the field. I have set up an error span element as an example of how I am trying to handle it.

Here is my code so far:

```
 <form name="register_form" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="full_name" pattern="B B" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Register"><br>
  <span class="error">Example error text based on validation</span>
</form>
</div>
  <script>
  function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value === '') {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Name must be filled out');
    } else if (textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Entered name is not correct');
    } else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Could any point me in the direction of how to take over the default alerts and use my own span element to display the alert text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to append a span tag with class error like this

Update:

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0];
if (node == undefined){
   node = document.createElement("span");
}
```

If you want to update error content

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value === '') {
        //textbox.setCustomValidity('Name must be filled out');
        var node = document.createElement("span");
        node.className = "error";
        node.innerHTML = 'Name must be filled out';
        //textbox.append(node);
        insertAfter(node, textbox);

    } else if (textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        //textbox.setCustomValidity('Entered name is not correct');
        var node = document.createElement("span");
        node.className = "error";
        node.innerHTML = 'Entered name is not correct';
        //textbox.append(node);
        insertAfter(node, textbox);
    } else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    return true;
}
```

```js
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value === '') {
        //textbox.setCustomValidity('Name must be filled out');
        var node = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0];
        //console.log(node)
        if (node == undefined){
            node = document.createElement("span");
        }
        node.className = "error";
        node.innerHTML = 'Name must be filled out';
        //textbox.append(node);
        var submit = document.getElementById('register');
      insertAfter(node, textbox);
        insertAfter(node, submit);
       
    } else if (textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        //textbox.setCustomValidity('Entered name is not correct');
        var node = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0];
         if (node == undefined){
            node = document.createElement("span");
        }
        node.className = "error";
        node.innerHTML = 'Entered name is not correct';
        //textbox.append(node);
  insertAfter(node, textbox);
    } else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    return true;
}

function insertAfter(newElement,targetElement) {
    // target is what you want it to go after. Look for this elements parent.
    var parent = targetElement.parentNode;

    // if the parents lastchild is the targetElement...
    if (parent.lastChild == targetElement) {
        // add the newElement after the target element.
        parent.appendChild(newElement);
    } else {
        // else the target has siblings, insert the new element between the target and it's next sibling.
        parent.insertBefore(newElement, targetElement.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

```css
.error{
color:red;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<form name="register_form" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="full_name" pattern="B B" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" required><br>
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register"><br>
  <!--<span class="error">Example error text based on validation</span>-->
</form>
```

Comment: Amazing! That is exactly what I wanted! Is there any way to append it after the submit button instead of after the field? How would I make the submit button the parent selector?

Comment: i updated answer, you can append after submit var submit = document.getElementById('register');   insertAfter(node, submit);

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly! Thank you! One last question, is there a way to update the text instead of creating a new element each time? Right now if the user clicks submit multiple times then multiple error spans are created.

Comment: i updated answer, you can get error element and update by innerHTML

Comment: I update answer for clicking submit multiple, if answer help you, you can mark it as accepted, thanks